# Manual Recovery

Tags: boot, apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I installed ubuntu 14.04.02 on my netbook. So now I've got 2 os on my netbook, windows 8 and ubuntu. When I boot my netbook and choose to open on ubuntu, it says

> serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.

then there is "

> press I to ignore, S to skip mounting, M for manual recovery.

I pressed "I", then it said

> The disk drive for /tmp is not ready yet or not present

(but my bootable usb drive is still inserted on my netbook; is there a problem with the usb drive?) And under it, it says,

> Continue to wait, Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.

I waited for almost 3 hours but nothing is happening so I decided to press "S". Then it says "

> An error occurred while mounting/. Press S to skip mounting or M for
>   manual recovery.

I pressed S again, then the screen turned black and looked like a terminal.

It looked like this:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS ubuntu ttyl (or tty1; i'm not sure)
ubuntu login: helen
password:(I entered the password)
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64)

*Documentation: http://help.ubuntu.com/

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available: 39:   /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available: Read-only file system
cat: /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available exited with return code 1
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: 39: /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd: cannot create /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available: Read-only file system
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 33: /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: cannot create /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: Read-only file system
cat: /var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: exited with return code 1

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

helen@ubuntu:~$
```

(What should I do next? I just want to use ubuntu, please help me,I don't really understand things here. Thank you.)

PS: I just typed the codes so I'm not sure if it is that accurate, but I checked it.